# How to calculate the slope/derivative of a bezier curve at a given t?

Tags: python, graphics, bezier, curve, calculus

```
DEFAULT_CONTROL_POINTS = [(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0)]

def factorial(n):
    result = 1
    while n > 1:
        result *= n
        n -= 1
    return result
    
def binomial_coefficient(n, k):
    return factorial(n) / (factorial(k) * factorial(n - k))


class BezierCurve(Curve):

    def __init__(self, control_points=None):
        if control_points is None:
            control_points = DEFAULT_CONTROL_POINTS

        self.control_points = control_points

    def get_order(self):
        return len(self.control_points) - 1

    def B(self, n, k, t):
        result = binomial_coefficient(n, k)
        result *= (1 - t) ** k
        result *= t ** (n - k)
        return result

    def calculate_point_multiplier(self, t):
        res_x = 0
        res_y = 0

        n = self.get_order()
        for k in range(n + 1):
            point = self.control_points[k]
            multiplier = B(n, k, t)
            res_x += point[0] * multiplier
            res_y += point[1] * multiplier

        return res_x, res_y

    def calculate_point_at(self, t):
        return self.calculate_point_multiplier(t, self.B)

    def calculate_slope_at(self, t):
        pass
```

Here, in the method `calculate_slope_at`, I need to be able to determine the slope of the curve at the point at the given `t`.

I need this so that I can move objects on the curve and have them face in the right direction as they're moving along the curve.

I need here a single value, the slope of the tangent line at a given `t`.

Comment: Your question as little to do with Python, so you might have better luck asking it on [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Like this: https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#derivatives (skip to the end of the section to see how ludicrously trivial derivatives are) - also _do not implement factorials_, because you don't want factorials, all you want are binomial coefficients, and those are so simple to compute you should just hardcode a whole slew of them and compute the rest using Pascal's triangle.